# What is the difference between wlan0 and wlan1 interface on raspberry Pi Model 3

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I have seen in /etc/network/interfaces file on my new raspberry Pi Model 3, two entries for wifi connections:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Why is there 2 interfaces for wifi ?

Thanks